# not equals <> operator not working

Tags: javascript

When I use greater or less than symbol (`< >`) in code it returns a wrong result - for example when I enter 2 and 10, It returns 2 is bigger and 10 is smaller!

I know that I can use `Math.max(a,b)` then it returns the right result but I want to know: why does it return the wrong result? Am I wrong?

Please explain this for me. Thank you. (;

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>showing the bigger an smaller number</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
        function b(){ 
            var a=document.getElementById("a").value;
            var b=document.getElementById("b").value;
            if (a>b){document.getElementById("o").innerHTML="a is bigger : "+a}
            else {if (a<b){document.getElementById("o").innerHTML="b is bigger : "+b}}
        }
        function k(){ 
            var a=document.getElementById("a").value;
            var b=document.getElementById("b").value;
            if (a>b){document.getElementById("o").innerHTML="b is smaller : "+b}
            else {if (a<b){document.getElementById("o").innerHTML="a is smaller : "+a}}
        }
    </script>
    <style>
       small {
           font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
           color:#666;
       }
       input { 
           height:30px;
           width:175px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" id="a" placeholder="type first Number here"></input><b>&nbsp;</b>
    <input  type="number" id="b" placeholder="type second number here"></input>
    <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button onClick="b();">show me the bigger Number</button>
    <button onclick="k();">show me the smaller Number</button>
    <br><b></b>
    <br><small id="o">&nbsp;</small>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry if my English was bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try parsing the values as floats. At the moment, you're comparing strings:

```
var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").value),
    b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b").value);
```

Of course, this is going to cause problems if the user enters something other than a valid numerical value...

Comment: it worked!but why didnt my code work?is it a bug just for javascript?is it a bug or i am writing the code wrong?

Comment: No, it's not a bug. `.value` returns a string for inputs, so you need to parse the value.

Comment: do we have to do it in other Programming languages for example c++ ?

Comment: @user2557825 - Yes, there is similar behaviour in other languages. In a general sense many languages let you compare strings with `>` or `<`, where the operation is seeing which is first in terms of alphabetical order (or lexographic order, given that strings can contain non-alphabet characters). Also, many (most?) languages treat user input as strings, so some conversion is necessary before performing numerical operations on the values. As far as C++ goes, it does have methods like `scanf()`, which gets user input but you specify what data type the input should be taken as.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `!=` (not equal) or `!==` (not identical) relational operators instead of `<>`.